# Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged when using UISeachController iOS 8

Tags: ios8, uisearchcontroller

I get this warning when integrating `UISearchController` in iOS 8. I don't use storyboard in my project.

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged when using UISeachController iOS 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement UISearchControllerDelegate

Here is an example

```
 # pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

 - (void)presentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
 {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.